# Vector grid to raster error

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I try to raster grid layer using layer attribute and I get rasterization error.
Initially I have a layer with a grid and a line layer with several lines. The line layer has an attribute ("az" - it's amizuth of line) and I want to add this attribite to grid layer. Each cell of the grid must have a nearest line attribute value. I use Join attributes by nearest tool.
[image]

Then I raster my grid using attribute value to get a cost raster (cost raster is my goal). And I get an error - only few cells are rasterized. In this case only one cell. But I have attributes for all cells of the layer.
[image]

I don't have any idea why it has hapenned but I've got such results with different layers.
May be somebody could help me and there is more effective way to add attributes to cell layer or may be I'm doing something wrong with rasterization?
I've loaded my layers in here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RuKx3SAP8Lw8eRF68IZWmOkPPjrlvSvM?usp=sharing

Comment: But most of the time more than one line crosses the grids. Therefore Join attributes by nearest tool. returns -Multiple matching features found at the same distance from search feature, found 2 features instead of 1. How should these cases be handled?